# issue with filehandling (EBADF with fopen/fwrite) with samba-share

Tags: c, fopen, samba

for many months I used `fopen(...,"rw")` for read/write-access to some data files (*.DBF) and could write specific records at every position I wanted. `(fseek() .. fwrite() etc.)`
Now I get the error EBADF (9) bad file descriptor explicitly at call to fwrite().
I tested fopen() also with

- "r+" --> EOPNOTSUPP (95),
- "r+w" --> EOPNOTSUPP (95),
- "a+" not usable appends only at the end
- possible modes with "w" at first pos. truncate/delete the file...

System: Linux Mint 18.3 und 19, Cinnamon; Kernel 4.18.0-25 bzw. 4.15.0-88;
IDE code::blocks svn 12286; g++  7.5.0 bzw. 5.4.0;
Samba: 4.7.6 bzw. 4.3.11

Has anybody an idea whats going wrong?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: perhaps I can clearify my problem: the operations work fine with "r", "w" and "a" but don't with "rw".